# All items overwritten by the last item when using pipeline to save picture in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to scrapy and not a native English speaker, so sorry in advance if I make some silly mistakes or cannot make my point clear.I want to scrapy the information and covers of rock albums from  a Chinese website (music.douban.com/tag/%E6%91%87%E6%BB%9A?start=0&type=T). When I am just using xpath to get non-picture information(artists,the detail page's url and the cover's url),nothing went wrong:

```
import scrapy
from myscrapy.items import musicItem

class doubanAlbumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "albumspider"
    start_urls = ['https://music.douban.com/tag/%E6%91%87%E6%BB%9A?start=0&type=T']
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://music.douban.com/tag/%E6%91%87%E6%BB%9A?start=0&type=T'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=self.headers)
    
    def parse(self,response):
        item = musicItem()
        albums = response.xpath(r"//tr[@class='item']")
        for album in albums:
            item['alname'] = " ".join(album.xpath(r"./td/div/a/text()")[0].extract().split())
            item['detailUrl'] = album.xpath(r"./td/a/@href")[0].extract()
            item['imageUrl'] = (r"/m/").join(album.xpath(r"./td/a/img/@src")[0].extract().split(r"/s/"))
            yield(item)
```

```
class musicItem(scrapy.Item):
    alname = scrapy.Field()
    imageUrl = scrapy.Field()
    detailUrl = scrapy.Field()
    image = scrapy.Field()
    image_paths = scrapy.Field()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAJef.png)

But when I added a pipeline to download tye pictures, the pictures are downloaded successfully, while the non-picture info went wrong. They are all overwritten by the last item, which is In the Court of the Crimson King.
Have anyone else similar problems?

```
class DoubanImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    default_headers = {
        'accept': 'image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
        'cookie': 'bid=yQdC/AzTaCw',
        'referer': 'https://www.douban.com/',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
    }
 
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['imageUrl'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI9c6.png)

Comment: have you enabled all of the correct settings to activate the image downloader?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you mean images_url_fields and other things in settings.py? Yes, and images are downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Item fields are mutable, and right now in your `parse` method you create 1 item at the beginning of your method body and use that same item when you yield each of the results.  What you need to do is create a unique item on each iteration of your `for loop`.

For example:

```
    def parse(self,response):
        albums = response.xpath(r"//tr[@class='item']")
        for album in albums:
            item = musicItem()
            item['alname'] = " ".join(album.xpath(r"./td/div/a/text()")[0].extract().split())
            item['detailUrl'] = album.xpath(r"./td/a/@href")[0].extract()
            item['imageUrl'] = (r"/m/").join(album.xpath(r"./td/a/img/@src")[0].extract().split(r"/s/"))
            yield(item)
```